# How to store Polygon Coordinates as WKT Literal Values using RDFLIB?

Tags: python, rdf, rdfs, fuseki, rdflib

I am working on GEOSPARQL queries. And I want to store Polygon Coordinates as wktLiteral values using RDF Graph (RDFLIB python). Currently I am doing that using the below code.

GEO = Namespace("http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#")

```
if name == "wkt":
   self._graph.add((image, GEO["asWKT"], rl.Literal(value, datatype=GEO.wktGeneral)))
```

But when I see results in my Apache Fuseki server. I am not able to see proper datatype for "POLYGON(()) coordinates". Please let me know if anything is missing. Thank you.

[image: Results Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, URIRef, Namespace

GEO = Namespace("http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#")

g = Graph()
g.bind("geo", GEO)
x = URIRef("x:")
g.add((x, GEO["asWKT"], Literal("value", datatype=GEO.wktLiteral)))


print(g.serialize(format="turtle").decode("utf-8"))
```

This returns the datatype just fine.

- you need to set the type to `wktLiteral`, not `wktGeneral`
- you need to use `Literal()` directly, not `rl.Literal()`

There may be other things but you've not presented enough code for me to tell.

Comment: Below is my code

import rdflib as rl
query_endpoint = "http://localhost:3030/example/query"
update_endpoint = "http://localhost:3030/example/update"

BACKEND = sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore()
BACKEND.open((query_endpoint, update_endpoint))
GEO = Namespace("http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#")
GRAPH = rl.Graph(BACKEND, identifier="http://project/base/default")
### Consider value ###
value = "POLYGON(())"

self_graph = GRAPH
ex = Namespace("http://example.org/#")
self_graph.add((ex, GEO["asWKT"], rl.Literal(value, datatype=GEO.wktLiteral)))

Comment: I am creating graph using RDFLIB and then trying to store in Apache Fuseki Jena

Comment: I get output like this in Fuseki server. "POLYGON((8.466972112655641 48.997951481364986,8.466972112655641 48.99809578146089,8.467175960540773 48.99809578146089,8.467175960540773 48.997951481364986,8.466972112655641 48.997951481364986))"^^

"POLYGON((8.467036485671999 48.99954579824209,8.467036485671999 48.99961618633192,8.467197418212892 48.99961618633192,8.467197418212892 48.99954579824209,8.467036485671999 48.99954579824209))"^^